# netty backward compatiblity with older library

Tags: netty

My netty project  uses consumes old version of **netty (3.X series)** now when i see the **4.x** version there is significant difference in the declaration of the package for e.g in 3.9 libary
we have import declaration starting with **org.jboss**

```
import org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketChannelFactory;
```

in 4.x

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
```

it causes me recompile the entire project with new imports, the client(end users) still using the old version of library and might not be interested in upgrade with new library, does netty will will be backword compatible with old API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netty 4 is not backward compatible with netty 3, but if by "client" you mean remote peer, it is ok to upgrade your server and keep compatible with client. the client just communicates with server over tcp stack and it doesn't care about how the server is implemented.